# JSON response list select

Tags: python, json

I'm fiddling with an API and this is the response i get:

```
{
  "name1": {
  },
  "name2": {
    "something1": 213,
    "something2": [
      {
        "info1": 123,
        "info2": 324
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've tried using

```
r.json()['name2']['something2']['info2'][0]
```

and

```
r.json()['name2']['something2'][0]
```

the first one gives me an error while the second one prints "something2" in its entirety, which i only need specific infos and values from there. How can I do that?

Comment: `r.json()['name2']['something2'][0]['info2']`

Comment: what value(s) are you trying to grab from the json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use the following code

```
data = r.json()
data['name2']['something2'][0]['info2']
```

You need to put [0] after something2 because something2 is a list

Comment: Yeah Selcuk already said it in a comment but thanks regardless!